# pandas outcome variable is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have set the outcome variable `y` as a column in a csv. It loads properly and works when I print just `y`, but when I use `y = y[x:]` I start getting `NaN` as values.

```
y = previous_games_stats['Unnamed: 7'] #outcome variable (win/loss)
y = y[9:] #causes NaN for outcome variables
```

Then later in the file I print the outcome column. `final_df` is a dataframe which does not yet have the outcome variable set, so I set it below:

```
final_df['outcome'] = y
print(final_df['outcome'])
```

But the outcome is:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9      L
```

It looks like the last value is correct (they should all be 'W' or 'L').

**How can I line up my data frames properly so I do not get NaN?**

Entire Code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

from array import array

iris=load_iris()

previous_games_stats = pd.read_csv('stats/2016-2017 CANUCKS STATS.csv', header=1)
numGamesToLookBack = 10;
                         axis=1) #Predictor variables

X = previous_games_stats[['GF', 'GA']]
count = 0
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['GF', 'GA'])

#final_y = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Unnamed: 7'])

y = previous_games_stats['Unnamed: 7'] #outcome variable (win/loss)
y = y[numGamesToLookBack-1:]



for game in range(0, 10):
  X = previous_games_stats[['GF', 'GA']]
  X = X[count:numGamesToLookBack] #num games to look back
  stats_feature_names = list(X.columns.values)

  df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

  stats_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names).sum().to_frame().T
  final_df = final_df.append(stats_df, ignore_index=True)

  count+=1
  numGamesToLookBack+=1



print("final_df:\n", final_df)



stats_target_names = np.array(['Win', 'Loss']) #don't need?...just a label it looks like

df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)

final_df['outcome'] = y
final_df['outcome'].update(y) #ADDED UPDATE TO FIX NaN



df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75 #for iris


final_df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(final_df)) <= .65


train, test = df[df['is_train']==True], df[df['is_train']==False]
stats_train = final_df[final_df['is_train']==True]
stats_test = final_df[final_df['is_train']==False]


features = df.columns[:4]
stats_features = final_df.columns[:2]


y = pd.factorize(train['species'])[0]
stats_y = pd.factorize(stats_train['outcome'])[0]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
stats_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)


clf.fit(train[features], y)
stats_clf.fit(stats_train[stats_features], stats_y)

stats_clf.predict_proba(stats_test[stats_features])[0:10]



preds = iris.target_names[clf.predict(test[features])]
stats_preds = stats_target_names[stats_clf.predict(stats_test[stats_features])]




pd.crosstab(stats_test['outcome'], stats_preds, rownames=['Actual Outcome'], colnames=['Predicted Outcome'])
print("~~~confusion matrix~~~\nColumns represent what we predicted for the outcome of the game, and rows represent the actual outcome of the game.\n")
print(pd.crosstab(stats_test['outcome'], stats_preds, rownames=['Actual Outcome'], colnames=['Predicted Outcome']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected, because `y` have no indices (no data) for first `9` values, so after assign back get `NaN`s.

If column is new and length of `y` is same as length of `df` assign numpy array:

```
final_df['outcome'] = y.values
```

---

But if lengths are different, it is a bit complicated, because need same lengths:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10), 'b':range(20,30)}).astype(str).radd('a')
print (df)
    a    b
0  a0  a20
1  a1  a21
2  a2  a22
3  a3  a23
4  a4  a24
5  a5  a25
6  a6  a26
7  a7  a27
8  a8  a28
9  a9  a29

y = df['a']
y = y[4:]
print (y)
4    a4
5    a5
6    a6
7    a7
8    a8
9    a9
Name: a, dtype: object
```

---

**`len(final_df) < len(y)`**:

Filter `y` by `final_df`, then convert to numpy array for not align indices:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'new':range(100, 105)})
final_df['s'] = y.iloc[:len(final_df)].values
print (final_df)
   new   s
0  100  a4
1  101  a5
2  102  a6
3  103  a7
4  104  a8
```

**`len(final_df) > len(y)`**:

Create new `Series` by filtered `index` values:

```
final_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'new':range(100, 110)})
final_df1['s'] = pd.Series(y.values, index=final_df1.index[:len(y)])
print (final_df1)
   new    s
0  100   a4
1  101   a5
2  102   a6
3  103   a7
4  104   a8
5  105   a9
6  106  NaN
7  107  NaN
8  108  NaN
9  109  NaN
```

Comment: Oh ok, so how can I make the indices start at 9 instead of 0? That should solve the problem right?

Comment: @tom44 - `outcome` is new or existing column?

Comment: It is the new column. I posted the entire code, and i'm not sure where to use `final_df['outcome'].update(y)`

Comment: I added this line `final_df['outcome'].update(y) #ADDED UPDATE TO FIX NaN` in the entire code in the question. Is that the correct place to put the update? It is not working

Comment: @tom44 - I think not. So I guess `final_df` have only `10` lines. Do you need assign values from `y = y[9:]` to new column? If need assign values from `9` to `19` row (10 values) need `y = y[9:19]` and `final_df['outcome'] = y.values`.

Comment: I tried y.values but got `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. I also tried `print("YYY???:\n",y)`
`final_df['outcome'] = y` and y prints out correctly, but final_df['outcome'] ] y still produces NaN values, even with `.update(y)`

Comment: @tom44 -  Ithink `update` here is wrong, because new column. Please check edited answer.